# Mocking zipfile in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock

I'm trying to use Python mock library to mock few methods for zipfile module.

Example Source which I want to test:

```
def zipStuff(listOfPathToFiles):
    with ZipFile(fName, 'w') as archive:
        for each in listOfPathToFiles:
             archive.write(each, strippedfName)
    return archive
```

The "archive" above will be ignored for normal execution, but will be list of files during tests.

Example unittest code:

```
emptyList=[]

def mockWrite(fName):
    emptyList.append(fName)
    return

mockZip.__enter__ = Mock(return_value=emptyList)
mockZip.__exit__ = Mock(return_value=True)
```

Now, I want to mock archive.write so that instead of actual write call, it is replaced by mockWrite function so I can get a list of all files that were supposed to be zipped.

I've tried:

```
mockZip.write = Mock(side_effect=mockWrite)
```

but this wasn't being called. Debugging shows the function is calling mockZip.**enter**().write. If I try:

```
mockZip.__enter__().write = Mock(side_effect=mockWrite)
```

Python issues error that 'list' has no attribute write (which is correct). I'm new to Mock and Python and would really appreciate any pointers. Suggestions?

Comment: `mockZip.__enter__ = (return_value=emptyList)` invalid syntax

Comment: I wrote the code here, and again missed the Mock calls. The correct syntax is Mock(return_value=emptyList). Modified the original question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of having `mockZip.__enter__` return an empty list, have it return an object like the following:

```
class MockZipFile:
    def __init__(self):
        self.files = []
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.files)
    def write(self, fname):
        self.files.append(fname)
```

You can add methods and implementations as needed to suit your mocking needs.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using this now!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that the function is called **enter** using contextlib (https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) and not **entry**. Changing this mock should solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry I meant to write __enter__ and not __entry__. I've edited the post to reflect this.